# Keep icons centered when screen changes in JQM footer

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

How can I keep the icons centered in the JQM footer when different screen sizes are applied? I have tested the app on the iPhone 6 plus and they are fine there but when the screen size is reduced the icons do not adjust to the new screen size. I have tried text-align: center, also adjusting the margin too but that did not give me the result I'm looking for. It's probably something so simple, any help is appreciated.

My html

```
<div data-role="footer" id="socials" data-position="fixed">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia"><img src="styles/images/wikipedia.png" alt="wikipedia" width="42" height="42"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="styles/images/google-plus.png" alt="google plus" width="42" height="42"></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.bing.com"><img src="styles/images/bing.png" alt="bing" width="42" height="42"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com"><img src="styles/images/yahoo.png" alt="yahoo" width="42" height="42"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img src="styles/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" width="42" height="42"></a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
#Asia div ul #socials {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#Asia div ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the jQM navbar:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="socials" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/42/42/technics/1/" alt="wikipedia" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/42/42/technics/2/" alt="google plus" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/42/42/technics/3/" alt="bing" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/42/42/technics/4/" alt="yahoo" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/42/42/technics/5/" alt="linkedin" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fr1na6cg/)**